# Managing big images in a game

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es

I'm developing a side scrolling shooter, and as background I have a set  of images (about 15 images in 1024x1024 in png). and with the sprites of the enemies, and shots, I'm starting to have some memory issues.

I tried to use PVRTC texture but the image is not as shiny as it should be.

Should I load the texture on the go ? 
What os your strategy in texture management ?

Thank you for the help

Comment: Have you tried, for performance comparison purpose, some third party frameworks like the excellent http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/ ?

Comment: I thought about that, but I fear that now I'm advanced in my project I should break a lot of code...

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Aymarick comment.
There is good solution in cocos2d for asynchronous texture loading:
[https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/develop/cocos2d/CCTextureCache.m:](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/develop/cocos2d/CCTextureCache.m)

```
-(void) addImageAsync: (NSString*)path target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector
```

So you keep in memory your in-game screen texture and left/right screens. During scrolling (for example in right direction) you unload not visible left texture, set current screen texture as left, right texture as current screen, and asynchronously load new right texture.

But I would prefer tiled background if it is possible by art design.

Answer (score 0):

> *"I tried to use PVRTC texture but the image is not as shiny as it
>   should be."*

Out of curiosity, which compression tool did you use? IMG's [PVRTextool](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-pvrtextool.asp) is sometimes better than those that get bundled with some dev packages and, I believe, a newer version (with completely rewritten compressor code) *should* be available in the not too distant future.

Comment: I use the PVRTextool maybe there is a specific command that work better, what is your's ?

Comment: Ok - I thought maybe you may have been using the Apple one. In that case, with the exception of increasing the number of iteration passes, I don't think there'll be much to gain before the new version comes out. Since the textures are for the background, I assume they are opaque?

As for what my compressor is; I've been working, on and off, on the next version of the library that PVRTexTool is built on. Actually, I'd be curious as to what type of textures are proving troublesome - I can always use more "real" data in my test suite.